# How to solve this "Caution: request is not finished yet in chrome"

Tags: json, ajax, request

I am facing an issue related to loading **JSON** data.

When I monitor **JSON** call on Developer Tools of Chrome, I get the following message in the network tab of Chrome Developer Tools.

> **Caution: request is not finished yet**

Attaching a snip for reference:

[image]

Comment: Might be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847083/chrome-just-doesnt-finish-loading-js-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome just doesn't finish loading JS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847083/chrome-just-doesnt-finish-loading-js-files)

Comment: I doubt it is a duplicate of indicated issue above. We are having same problem after update to chrome version 62. Response is text/html in our case and no keep alive is requested. Chrome for some reason think there will be more response but in reality all was already received and processed by app. Its just makes it difficult to examine result in inspector as it does not populate preview and response tabs.

Comment: Having this same problem. Any resolution @hiral shah?

Comment: Have you resolved this?  Did that 6MB of JSON ever finish loading on the client?  If not, can you post the code that is making the request.

Answer (score 24):

It is caused by two-step response loading. If you are using some low-level `API`, make sure that you fetch not only headers, which arrive first, but also body content that comes later as a stream.

I had the same issue when using the `fetch` function in `JavaScript`. To solve it, make sure you call a method that reads the body of the response like `json()` or `text()`:

```js
// Sends request and loads only headers
fetch('/foo');

// Sends request, loads headers and then fetches the body as JSON
fetch('/foo').then(response => response.json());
```

In my case response headers were also loaded properly and I had a successful `HTTP` status code, but I was missing the body content and I had *`Caution: request is not finished yet`* inside `Chrome Developer Tools`.

Comment: Is this behavior expected? I was freaking out and your comment saved my day. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to kill such requests?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue due to a programming error that caused an infinite loop in my JavaScript code.

Some time ago Chrome would point out that a script is stuck, but for some reason such a message did not show up in my Chrome. Instead, I found this error in the network tab.

Trying Firefox, it showed the error message "This page is slowing down Firefox. To speed up your browser, stop this page".
This helped me figure out that in my case the issue was not related to the request, but was actually caused by a script running forever.

Apparently, the infinite loop in JavaScript causes Chrome to not finalize the request or at least it does not update this display. I am not sure why Chrome would not show a more meaningful error message that a script is stuck.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I needed to use `response.text()` instead of just using `response`. The usage of  just `response` yields in "Caution: request is not finished yet"

```
fetch("API_URL_GOES_HERE", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
```

A tip here would be: Open Postman's Code snippet and view the actual JS Fetch that is happening.

Answer (score 0):

consider removing all extensions and closing all the browser tabs
for me it helped - upon restart, all is well.
So strange

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had Chrome configured for throttling to simulate 3G (slow network) speeds -- and I forgot to disable that setting when I was done with those tests.

Chrome --> Inspect --> Network --> Network Throttling --> Set to "No Throttling"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).